# How to make emysql return utf-8 encoded binaries

Tags: mysql, utf-8, erlang

I'm using `emysql` to fetch data from `mysql` database.

Adding pool like this:

```
emysql:add_pool(my_pool, 1, MysqlUser, MysqlPassword, MysqlHost, PortInt, MysqlDatabase, utf8),

emysql_util:as_record(emysql:execute(...))
```

of prepared statement returns list or records which have binaries (strings in databases). This binaries are `latin1-encoded`, while in database they are `utf-8` strings with `cyrillic` symbols.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most common problems that exists, you can try to run your erlang shell with

```
erl +pc unicode
```

This forces erlang to run on utf-8

so for example you will see this

```
Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)  
1> [1024].
"Ѐ"
2> [1070,1085,1080,1082,1086,1076].
"Юникод"
3> [229,228,246].
"åäö"
4> <<208,174,208,189,208,184,208,186,208,190,208,180>>.
<<"Юникод"/utf8>>
5> <<229/utf8,228/utf8,246/utf8>>.
<<"åäö"/utf8>>
```

also I recommend to you to check this talk from 'Patrik Nyblom'  on 'handling unicoed' which he gave on erlang user conference in Stockholm this year. [Here](https://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/847/PatrikEUC2013.pdf)

If you go through this you can find many useful stuff to handle your problem

Good luck

Comment: this feature appeared in R16?

Comment: yes and I think there are some minor bugs in there but it works fine if you dont go crazy with it and soon enough it will be complete!